# How to submit a form in Semantic UI?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, semantic-ui

I know how to validate a form using [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/), and can even read in console the message "Form has no validation errors, submitting." However, where is this submitting to? I want to actually submit the form, but the way Semantic UI is laid out I don't seem to be able to specify where to submit to or anything.

I read [this tutorial](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/10/semantic-ui-and-angularjs-basic-registration-form-with-validation/), but that uses Angular for submission and not just Semantic UI.

Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: have you tried reading their own documentations about it ??

Comment: Does your form not have an "action" attribute where the related php function/file is called?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I have read their documentation, but as far as I can see there is no documentation on the submitting. There is documentation on validating the data, but nothing specific on the submitting. [link](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/form.html) says "submit" submits a selected form, but there is no actual explanation of where it submits to.

Comment: @Sebsemillia I wish. The way Semantic UI is built, they do not use HTML form elements.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use jQuery's ajax:

```
   //Get value from an input field
   function getFieldValue(fieldId) { 
      // 'get field' is part of Semantics form behavior API
      return $('.ui.form').form('get field', fieldId).val();
   }

   function submitForm() {
      var formData = {
          field1: getFieldValue('someId')
      };

      $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: '/api/someRestEndpoint', data: formData, success: onFormSubmitted });
   }

   // Handle post response
   function onFormSubmitted(response) {
        // Do something with response ...
   }
```

EDIT: also, you can use the onSuccess method of the form to run the submitForm function, ie when you initialize the form:

```
$('.ui.form').form(validationRules, { onSuccess: submitForm });
```

onSuccess will only be called when the 'Submit' button is clicked and the form is valid based on the rules you specify.

EDIT: If you want the regular HTML form behavior, you will need to add the semantic css classes to the `form` tag.

```
<form class="ui form" method="POST" action="/signup">...</form>
```

And then you set up the validation rules using jQuery. This will give you the default HTML form behavior, ie when you hit the submit button, it will make a POST request to /signup in the case above. If any of your rules trigger, the submit is prevented until there is no validation errors.

Comment: Good work for being the only place on the web where I could find an example of using the onSuccess callback.

Comment: "onSuccess will only be called when the 'Submit' button is clicked and the form is valid based on the rules you specify" - that would be perfect but the onSuccess is called when the page loads rather than when the button is clicked. Any clues?

Comment: @silverdr I also see this, it doesn't seem to wait for the verification!

Answer (score 10):

use the original submit button but add semantic button style:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui button" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui teal button big"/>
```

Comment: do you know how to add an icon to that input? Something like: `<i class="sign in icon">`

Comment: their tutorial never mentions this in the form examples !!

Comment: If your using the document ready validationRules() implementation, this doesn't work because it automatically submits the page.

Comment: @Niklas - you cannot put HTML inside an `<input/>`, however you can use `<button type="submit" class="ui button"><i class="sign in icon"> Sign in</button>`. This will also submit the form, but I think it might not work on older browsers.

Answer (score 10):

Semantic UI has it's own API to submit form. for example:

```
$('.ui.form .submit.button')
.api({
    url: 'server.php',
    method : 'POST',
    serializeForm: true,
    beforeSend: function(settings) {
    },
    onSuccess: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you want to run the form validation module first?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet which is surely all the time!

Comment: @Billybobbonnet, in that case you should add the validations on the .form section.

Comment: For me that is the best approach, we would be using the built-in functions.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to retrofit a standard HTML form use the code below.

Start with a basic working standard HTML form with a submit button and this will take your values and post them to your form destination, returning the output below your form submit button.

1. Its a good time to double check you are successfully linking to jquery, semantic javascript and semantic css at this point.
2. Add class="ui form" to your form tag .
3. Add the javascript below.

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// validation 
 $('.ui.form').form({
    email: {
      identifier : 'email',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'email',
          prompt : 'Please enter an email'
        }
      ]
    }
},
{
    inline: true,
    on: 'blur',
    transition: 'fade down', 
    onSuccess: validationpassed
});

// called if correct data added to form 
function validationpassed() {

    // Multiple instances may have been bound to the form, only submit one.
    // This is a workaround and not ideal. 
    // Improvements welcomed. 

    if (window.lock != "locked") { 
        var myform = $('.ui.form');
        $.ajax({
            type: myform.attr('method'),
            url: myform.attr('action'),
            data: myform.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                //if successful at posting the form via ajax.
                myformposted(data);
                window.lock = "";
            }
        });
    } 
    window.lock = "locked";
}

// stop the form from submitting normally 
$('.ui.form').submit(function(e){ 
    //e.preventDefault(); usually use this, but below works best here.
    return false;
});




function myformposted(data) { 
    // clear your form and do whatever you want here 
    $('.ui.form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    //$('.ui.submit.button').after("<div>Message sent. Thank you.</div>");
    $('.ui.submit.button').after(data);
} 

});
```

Basic form:

```
    <form action="process.php" method="post" class="ui form">
    <div class="field">
    <label>title</label>
        <input name="email" type="text">
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" class="ui button"/>
    </form>
```

If you want the error message to show in a box rather than within the form itself include this in your form, and remove the words "inline: true," and Semantic UI does the rest:

```
<div class="ui info message"></div>
```

NOTE: Using form tags with Semantic UI isn't strictly necessary as you only really need a div with the classes "ui form", however this retrofit code does require a form tag.

Answer (score 4):

What if you don't wana use ajax?!

Use this one:

```
$( "#reg_btn" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#register_form').submit();

});
```

in this case u can use `<button>` tag... there is no need to use classic  tag instead

Comment: Those submitting without ajax can simply remove the onSuccess part including the function

Answer (score 0):

Semantic UI is based on jQuery and CSS so if you want to submit your form data you have some way to do that:

1. Send your form data with AJAX
2. Use some jqQuery plugins like [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)
3. Trick!

   Put a submit button and set its display to none. When a user clicks on the `div` button throw that event to the submit button, in this way:

   ```
   $("div_button_selector").on("click", function(){
      $("input[type='submit']").trigger('click');
   });
   ```

Comment: I had thought of that, but I still want to use the Semantic UI validation.

Answer (score 0):

See post [Adding errors to form validation doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829753/adding-errors-to-form-validation-doesnt-work/25145323#25145323) for form and error validation. Since Semantic UI is a client side tool for user interface, this is the php for "self submitting / same code page" contact email. Since the purpose of Semantic UI is not logic processing, what language and or method do you want to use for form submission? JS/jquery client side or serverside php, rails, etc.? Keep in mind Semantic UI is dependent on jquery.

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST["email"]))
{
    if ($_POST["email"] != "")
    {
        $from = htmlentities($_POST["email"]); 
        $subject = htmlentities($_POST["subject"]);
        $message = htmlentities($_POST["message"]);
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
        mail("valid-server-email-username@valid-server-address", $subject, $message, "From: $from\n");
        $_POST["email"] = "";
        $_POST["subject"] = "";
        $_POST["message"] = "";
        unset($GLOBALS['email']);
        header("location: /");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a form like this

```html
<div class="ui form segment">
  <p>Tell Us About Yourself</p>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input placeholder="First Name" name="name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="ui blue submit button">Submit</div>
</div>
```

you can use the foolowing script to send the form

```js
$('.ui.blue.submit.button').on('click', function() {
  submitForm();
});

function submitForm() {
  var formData = $('.ui.form.segment input').serializeArray(); //or .serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/handler',
    data: formData
  });
}
```