# Semantic ui check form, submit to php

Tags: jquery, html

Html form using semantic ui:

```
<div class="ui form" action="send.php" method="POST">
<div class="field">
<label>Name</label>
<div class="ui left labeled input">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Dries Roelvink">
<div class="ui corner label">
<i class="icon asterisk"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label>Email</label>
<div class="ui left labeled input">
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="dries@roelvink.nl">
<div class="ui corner label">
<i class="icon asterisk"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
</div>
<input class="ui blue submit button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</div>
```

My jquery file:

```
$('.ui.form')
  .form({
    name: {
      identifier: 'name',
      rules: [
        {
          type: 'empty',
          prompt: 'Please enter a name.'
        }
    email: {
      identifier: 'email',
      rules: [
        {
          type: 'empty',
          prompt: 'Please enter a valid email.'
        }
    message: {
      identifier: 'message',
      rules: [
        {
          type: 'empty',
          prompt: 'Please enter your message.'
        }
      ]
    }
  })
;
```

I am trying to check my form using the jquery file, than submitting it to my php file. For some reason my submit button wont work, and I dont know how to submit this form to any file.php?

Please help!

Comment: Thank you, I'll check. I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit a form the standard HTML way, try changing the `<div>` to a `<form>`

```
<form class="ui form" action="send.php" method="POST">
<div class="field">
<label>Name</label>
<div class="ui left labeled input">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Dries Roelvink">
<div class="ui corner label">
<i class="icon asterisk"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label>Email</label>
<div class="ui left labeled input">
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="dries@roelvink.nl">
<div class="ui corner label">
<i class="icon asterisk"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
</div>
<input class="ui blue submit button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

This should submit to your `send.php` without any problems, first ofcourse the jQuery validation must pass in order for the form to send.

Also see [How to submit a form in Semantic UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482258/how-to-submit-a-form-in-semantic-ui)